# AWS Device Farm error: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-device-farm

I'm testing an app in Amazon Device Farm and in some devices this error appear:

```
Built-in Explorer Test failed:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long 
org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat
and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
```

The problem is that I'm not using anything from `org.opencv` or any method like `n_mat()`.

What is this? What can I do to solve this?

Devices tested:

```
ASUS Memo Pad 7 5.0 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
LG Nexus 5X 6.0 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
Motorola Nexus 6    5.0 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
LG V10 (T-Mobile)   5.1.1   Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
Motorola Moto G - 3rd Gen   5.1.1   Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
Motorola Moto G - 2nd Gen   6.0 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
Motorola DROID Turbo (Verizon)  5.1 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
Dell Venue 8 7840   5.1 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
LG G3 (AT&T)    5.0.1   Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
LG V10 (AT&T)   5.1.1   Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
LG Nexus 5  6.0 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
ASUS Nexus 7 - 2nd Gen (WiFi)   5.0.1   Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
Huawei Nexus 6P 6.0 Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
HTC One M9 (Verizon)    5.0.2   Built-in Explorer Suite  Built-in Explorer Test
```

Comment: I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Are you getting this error on all of the devices that you mentioned? Can you share a run URL of the runs for which you got this error?

The Explorer tests uses explores the UI elements on the app and tries to exercise those elements. The error you are seeing should not be related to the Explorer tests but it always good to take a look before concluding.

Comment: AWS Device Team? You guys just earn a new fan! Is this link: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/c57fd7cb-63b9-40b6-b2df-f651ffe3cfb1/runs/70d53d7a-5fbe-488a-8d3b-78ba6a5dad80 ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link :) Taking a look at it

Comment: Wanted to update you that we haven't had any luck yet but I will keep you posted on why this error showed up.

Comment: All right.. Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I get same issue for about half the devices where I test and we don't use opencv. Maybe some library what we use uses this indirectly (firebase?).

Comment: Having the same issue on some devices here as well, and I'm not using OpenCV either but I am using Firebase